# mutt & attachment encoding

Tags: pdf, mutt, base64

So, I have a simple bash script that is intended to send a note to a user (say, the fictitious fflintstone@bedrock.com), where said note contains a short snippet of text (contained in the file message.txt), and an attachment (a PDF file, which I'll either call good.pdf or bad.pdf, as explained below).

The call to mutt (CentOS 7, mutt version available from official repos is 'only' 1.5.21) in the script (below) works fine (for a good.pdf)...

```
 /usr/bin/mutt -s "here is the file..." fflintstone@bedrock.com -a  good.pdf < message.txt
```

...except that for some PDF files (bad.pdf), the attachment is blank when I try to open it up (either within a mail client, or with a PDF reader after first detaching it from the email).

Both good.pdf and bad.pdf render fine in any one of a number of PDF readers I have (suggesting that they're 'legit' PDF files). If I attach good.pdf or bad.pdf using an email client -- like Thunderbird -- both attachments come through fine (neither are blank).

But, bad.pdf comes up blank *if* I try to send it as an attachment using mutt (at least, the version of mutt I can run from CentOS 7).

If I look at some of the mail header for the good.pdf that mutt sends correctly, I see

```
 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
 Content-Disposition: inline

 Here is the text piped in from message.txt

 Content-Type: application/octet-stream
 Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="good.pdf"
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

So, base64 encoding of the good.pdf file.

But for the bad.pdf file, which is coming up 'blank', I get the following:

```
 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
 Content-Disposition: inline

 Here is the text piped in from message.txt

 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
 Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="bad.pdf"
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

So, for some reason, mutt thinks the content type for bad.pdf is text/plain (instead of application/octet-stream), which I suspect is why it then uses quoted-printable for Content-Transfer-Encoding (instead of base64).

Again, all my PDF readers open both good.pdf and bad.pdf fine. And, all my email clients (Thunderbird being one of them) attach both .pdf files fine, and both pdf files are 'readable' (not blank) on receipt. Its only when I use mutt that the bad.pdf is sending out as blank. Clearly, there is something 'different' (internally) between the PDF files, but that isn't something I can easily suss out, or control (I collect the PDF files from various users, and am not generating them).

So, any suggestions on what to do? Or clues as to what the problem is? mutt is clearly 'reading' something internal in bad.pdf that is making it think (erroneously) that bad.pdf is *not* a PDF file (which it assuredly is). In contrast, Thunderbird (and Outlook, and Evolution, and a number of other 'mail clients') attach it just fine, without turning it 'blank'.

Is it worth trying to force base64 coding, and if so, what do I need to feed to the CLI call to mutt to 'make it so'?

Many thank in advance...

Comment: Please confirm that the bad PDF files do have a file extension `pdf`. Mutt first checks the mime.types file to match extensions to mime types. If no matching extension is found, the contents of the file are used to determine the type.

Comment: Uh, yeah, They're both PDF files -- good.pdf, and bad.pdf. As per my OP, they open fine with various PDF readers (which wouldn't happen unless they were both .pdf files).